# Why do we need ChangeNotifierProvider in flutter?

Tags: flutter

In the documentation the comment about ChangeNotifierProvider is as follows:

/// Creates a [ChangeNotifier] using `create` and automatically

/// disposes it when [ChangeNotifierProvider] is removed from the widget tree.

Could someone explains the reason why we need to use ChangeNotifierProvider class in a more layman language?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Do you mean the entire `ChangeNotifierProvider` class or the default constructor (the one you mentioned).

Comment: A ChangeNotifierProvider wraps a ChangeNotifier with "provider glue" so that it is automatically created as if you had an initState() and destroyed as if you had a dispose(), but with a lot less boilerplate.

Comment: Thanks for your comments!

I find the official tutorial gives a good answer to this question :)

https://docs.flutter.dev/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/simple